# Is there a Python function or method that displays object specifications?

Tags: python

Is there a built-in method for getting specification comments in Python that can be used instead of going back and reading them in the class definition? Specifically I'm trying to identify how many and what sort of arguments a object from an imported module takes.

I couldn't find an answer to this in the Python documentation and if it's already been answered on here I couldn't get it in search.

Comment: You can use the `Inspect` module. http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html It can get function names, arguments, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> help(randint)


Help on method randint in module random:

randint(self, a, b) method of random.Random instance
    Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
(END)
```

http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#help

with a custom class:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self, smile):
...             print(smile)
...
>>> help(Test)

Help on class Test in module __main__:

class Test(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, smile)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
(END)
```

Comment: And if you are using ipython as a shell: `Test?`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module, specifically [inspect.getmembers()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers):

> `inspect.getmembers(object[, predicate])`
>
> Return all the members of an
>   object in a list of (name, value) pairs sorted by name.

Example:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self, smile):
...         print(smile)
... 
>>> inspect.getmembers(Test, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
[('__init__', <unbound method Test.__init__>)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install [ipython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.11/interactive/reference.html) interactive shell and use `%pdoc`, `%pdef` macro:

> %pdoc : Print (or run through a pager if too long) the
>   docstring for an object. If the given object is a class, it will print
>   both the class and the constructor docstrings.
>
> %pdef : Print
>   the definition header for any callable object. If the object is a
>   class, print the constructor information.